# Apache: Use requested directory as a parameter

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, directory

Here's what I'd like to do:

If a user goes to `www.example.com/thislocation`, I'd like to redirect to a particular script and give it "thislocation" as a parameter.

So if a user navigated to `www.example.com/thislocation`, I'd like to redirect to `www.example.com/cgi-bin/test.pl?parameter=thislocation`, and similarily, if the user navigated to `www.example.com/thatlocation`, I'd like to redirect to `www.example.com/cgi-bin/test.pl?parameter=thatlocation`.

Is this possible with Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using .htaccess and the code for this is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cgi-bin/test.pl?parameter=$1 [L]
```